# leaflet markers not appearing

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet

```
for (var f=0; f<group.length; f++) {
    var longitude = group[f][1];
    var latitude = group[f][0];
    var popupText = group[f][2];

    var markerLocation = new L.LatLng(longitude,latitude);
    var marker = new L.Marker(markerLocation);
    mymap.addLayer(marker);

    marker.bindPopup(popupText);
}
```

my group array is in this format

```
 [0]
 [0]53.522753
 [1]-1.126298
 [2]ASB
```

my console is saying

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, 53.522731)
    at new M (leaflet.js:5)
    at create_marker (hello.html:212)
    at JSON_callback (hello.html:169)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (requests.js:26)
```

setting group

```
var group = [];
var n = 3;

for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < current_lat_lng.length; i++) {
    if (i >= n && i % n === 0)
        j++;
    group[j] = group[j] || [];
    group[j].push(current_lat_lng[i])
}
```

I think the object is correct? but I'm not sure why this is happening. any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Where do you set the value of `group[0][1]`?

Comment: Updated first post!

Comment: @Adam `L.LatLng(longitude,latitude)`: or the variables are mistaken, or the order of them is! Make sure you're dealing with them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for (var f=0; f<group.length; f++) {
    var longitude = group[f][1];
    var latitude = group[f][0];
    var popupText = group[f][2];

    if (longitude && latitude && popupText) {
        L.marker([latitude, longitude]).bindPopup(popupText).addTo(mymap);
    } else {
        console.error('group[' + f + '] has invalid entries:');
        console.error('longitude', longitude);
        console.error('latitude', latitude);
        console.error('popupText', popupText);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is better practice however, I don't think it'll fix the error he's facing.